# Bluetooth Low Energy Push Mode

Tags: android, push, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

With the release of Android L, I'm making an application that will utilize BLE in both modes. Some phones will be in the peripheral mode (i.e. GATT Servers), other phones will be in the central mode (i.e. GATT Clients). Exactly how each phone determines whether to be a client or a server is irrelevant.

The problem I run in to is that at one point, the GATT Servers will have to start pushing information to GATT Clients, and then have the GATT Clients respond. While I looked through the specifications and it says that communication is two-way, I'm not sure if this is a supported mode of communication. The obvious choice would be to reverse which roles play the server and client, but unfortunately the application's requirements prevent me from doing that (as the role that uses the GATT Client mode needs to maintain connections to multiple devices at once).

Is there a well-defined way for me to have GATT Servers "push" data to GATT Clients? Alternatively, is there a different option (perhaps use some sort of flag to establish a traditional Bluetooth connection) that would be a better option?

Comment: your 'push' sounds like the client asking for notification

Comment: I've done some research and it appears that what I'm looking for is called an Indication. I'll post a detailed answer when I have more Android-pertinent specifics.